# App Engine SDK Download with Cloud Endpoints V2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

We need to migrate our project to **Endpoints Frameworks 2.0** due to the v1 *deprecation on August '18*.

We use the App Engine SDK for Java download for Standard Environment and use it in Eclipse (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download).

The latest download is 1.9.62 - 2018-02-07 and it still has the **Endpoints V1** in it.

Can someone tell me if there's any plan of updating this to v2 before the v1 deprecation in August '18? Or if there is a App Engine SDK for Java with Endpoint v2 already somewhere?

(We dont use Maven or Gradle, so the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating) for migration doesnt work for us)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The download will not be updated to Endpoint v2.**

*Answer from Google:*

As shown in the documentation [1], this comes installed with GCloud. You then run 'gcloud components install app-engine-java' to install the additional required App Engine SDK for Java. Together you have both the new general Cloud Endpoints [2] and the older App Engine specific Endpoints.

Since the new Google Cloud Endpoints is not App Engine specific (as it can be used from any of the following environments [3]) it will not be packaged with App Engine and will instead continue to be offered as a separate service.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java#get_software

[2] https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/

[3] https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/

***Useful aditional information about the migration:***

https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe#cloud_endpoints